# ast.literal_eval syntax error on list in dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm playing around with the [Google Analytics dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/bigquery/google-analytics-sample) in pandas, and I'm having an issue.

The dataset has a column named `hits`, which contains a list of dictionaries, saved as a string. When I try to use `ast.literat_eval` to get the list of dictionaries, I get a syntax error pointing to this part of the dictionary:

```py
'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object)
```

I'm using the following code to try to convert the string:

```py
df['hits'] = df['hits'].apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x))
```

I don't really care about this piece of data so it's fine if I could just ignore this and keep that particular dictionary value as a string. Does anyone know how to either ignore the error and set that dictionary value to a string, or properly convert this array?

FYI, an entire cell of the hits column looks like this:

```
"[{'hitNumber': 1, 'time': 0, 'hour': 23, 'minute': 0, 'isSecure': None, 'isInteraction': True, 'isEntrance': True, 'isExit': None, 'referer': 'https://www.youtube.com/yt/about/', 'page': {'pagePath': '/home', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com', 'pageTitle': 'Home', 'searchKeyword': None, 'searchCategory': None, 'pagePathLevel1': '/home', 'pagePathLevel2': '', 'pagePathLevel3': '', 'pagePathLevel4': ''}, 'transaction': None, 'item': None, 'contentInfo': None, 'appInfo': {'name': None, 'version': None, 'id': None, 'installerId': None, 'appInstallerId': None, 'appName': None, 'appVersion': None, 'appId': None, 'screenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/home', 'landingScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/home', 'exitScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/signin.html', 'screenDepth': '0'}, 'exceptionInfo': {'description': None, 'isFatal': True, 'exceptions': None, 'fatalExceptions': None}, 'eventInfo': None, 'product': array([], dtype=object), 'promotion': array([], dtype=object), 'promotionActionInfo': None, 'refund': None, 'eCommerceAction': {'action_type': '0', 'step': 1, 'option': None}, 'experiment': array([], dtype=object), 'publisher': None, 'customVariables': array([], dtype=object), 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'type': 'PAGE', 'social': {'socialInteractionNetwork': None, 'socialInteractionAction': None, 'socialInteractions': None, 'socialInteractionTarget': None, 'socialNetwork': 'YouTube', 'uniqueSocialInteractions': None, 'hasSocialSourceReferral': 'Yes', 'socialInteractionNetworkAction': ' : '}, 'latencyTracking': None, 'sourcePropertyInfo': None, 'contentGroup': {'contentGroup1': '(not set)', 'contentGroup2': '(not set)', 'contentGroup3': '(not set)', 'contentGroup4': '(not set)', 'contentGroup5': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup1': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup2': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup3': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup4': '(entrance)', 'previousContentGroup5': '(entrance)', 'contentGroupUniqueViews1': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews2': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews3': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews4': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews5': None}, 'dataSource': None, 'publisher_infos': array([], dtype=object)}\n {'hitNumber': 2, 'time': 30507, 'hour': 23, 'minute': 1, 'isSecure': None, 'isInteraction': True, 'isEntrance': None, 'isExit': None, 'referer': None, 'page': {'pagePath': '/google+redesign/gift+cards', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com', 'pageTitle': 'Gift Cards', 'searchKeyword': None, 'searchCategory': None, 'pagePathLevel1': '/google+redesign/', 'pagePathLevel2': '/gift+cards', 'pagePathLevel3': '', 'pagePathLevel4': ''}, 'transaction': {'transactionId': None, 'transactionRevenue': None, 'transactionTax': None, 'transactionShipping': None, 'affiliation': None, 'currencyCode': 'USD', 'localTransactionRevenue': None, 'localTransactionTax': None, 'localTransactionShipping': None, 'transactionCoupon': None}, 'item': {'transactionId': None, 'productName': None, 'productCategory': None, 'productSku': None, 'itemQuantity': None, 'itemRevenue': None, 'currencyCode': 'USD', 'localItemRevenue': None}, 'contentInfo': None, 'appInfo': {'name': None, 'version': None, 'id': None, 'installerId': None, 'appInstallerId': None, 'appName': None, 'appVersion': None, 'appId': None, 'screenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/google+redesign/gift+cards', 'landingScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/home', 'exitScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/signin.html', 'screenDepth': '0'}, 'exceptionInfo': {'description': None, 'isFatal': True, 'exceptions': None, 'fatalExceptions': None}, 'eventInfo': None, 'product': array([{'productSKU': 'GGOEGGCX056299', 'v2ProductName': 'Gift Card - $25.00', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Gift Cards/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productRevenue': None, 'localProductRevenue': None, 'productPrice': 25000000, 'localProductPrice': 25000000, 'productQuantity': None, 'productRefundAmount': None, 'localProductRefundAmount': None, 'isImpression': True, 'isClick': None, 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': 1},\n       {'productSKU': 'GGOEGGCX056499', 'v2ProductName': 'Gift Card - $50.00', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Gift Cards/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productRevenue': None, 'localProductRevenue': None, 'productPrice': 50000000, 'localProductPrice': 50000000, 'productQuantity': None, 'productRefundAmount': None, 'localProductRefundAmount': None, 'isImpression': True, 'isClick': None, 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': 2},\n       {'productSKU': 'GGOEGGCX056199', 'v2ProductName': 'Gift Card- $100.00', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Gift Cards/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productRevenue': None, 'localProductRevenue': None, 'productPrice': 100000000, 'localProductPrice': 100000000, 'productQuantity': None, 'productRefundAmount': None, 'localProductRefundAmount': None, 'isImpression': True, 'isClick': None, 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': 3},\n       {'productSKU': 'GGOEGGCX056399', 'v2ProductName': 'Gift Card - $250.00', 'v2ProductCategory': 'Home/Gift Cards/', 'productVariant': '(not set)', 'productBrand': '(not set)', 'productRevenue': None, 'localProductRevenue': None, 'productPrice': 250000000, 'localProductPrice': 250000000, 'productQuantity': None, 'productRefundAmount': None, 'localProductRefundAmount': None, 'isImpression': True, 'isClick': None, 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'productListName': 'Category', 'productListPosition': 4}],\n      dtype=object), 'promotion': array([], dtype=object), 'promotionActionInfo': None, 'refund': None, 'eCommerceAction': {'action_type': '0', 'step': 1, 'option': None}, 'experiment': array([], dtype=object), 'publisher': None, 'customVariables': array([], dtype=object), 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'type': 'PAGE', 'social': {'socialInteractionNetwork': None, 'socialInteractionAction': None, 'socialInteractions': None, 'socialInteractionTarget': None, 'socialNetwork': 'YouTube', 'uniqueSocialInteractions': None, 'hasSocialSourceReferral': 'Yes', 'socialInteractionNetworkAction': ' : '}, 'latencyTracking': None, 'sourcePropertyInfo': None, 'contentGroup': {'contentGroup1': '(not set)', 'contentGroup2': '(not set)', 'contentGroup3': '(not set)', 'contentGroup4': '(not set)', 'contentGroup5': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup1': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup2': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup3': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup4': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup5': '(not set)', 'contentGroupUniqueViews1': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews2': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews3': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews4': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews5': None}, 'dataSource': None, 'publisher_infos': array([], dtype=object)}\n {'hitNumber': 3, 'time': 53670, 'hour': 23, 'minute': 1, 'isSecure': None, 'isInteraction': True, 'isEntrance': None, 'isExit': True, 'referer': None, 'page': {'pagePath': '/signin.html', 'hostname': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com', 'pageTitle': 'The Google Merchandise Store - Log In', 'searchKeyword': None, 'searchCategory': None, 'pagePathLevel1': '/signin.html', 'pagePathLevel2': '', 'pagePathLevel3': '', 'pagePathLevel4': ''}, 'transaction': None, 'item': None, 'contentInfo': None, 'appInfo': {'name': None, 'version': None, 'id': None, 'installerId': None, 'appInstallerId': None, 'appName': None, 'appVersion': None, 'appId': None, 'screenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/signin.html', 'landingScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/home', 'exitScreenName': 'shop.googlemerchandisestore.com/signin.html', 'screenDepth': '0'}, 'exceptionInfo': {'description': None, 'isFatal': True, 'exceptions': None, 'fatalExceptions': None}, 'eventInfo': None, 'product': array([], dtype=object), 'promotion': array([], dtype=object), 'promotionActionInfo': None, 'refund': None, 'eCommerceAction': {'action_type': '0', 'step': 1, 'option': None}, 'experiment': array([], dtype=object), 'publisher': None, 'customVariables': array([], dtype=object), 'customDimensions': array([], dtype=object), 'customMetrics': array([], dtype=object), 'type': 'PAGE', 'social': {'socialInteractionNetwork': None, 'socialInteractionAction': None, 'socialInteractions': None, 'socialInteractionTarget': None, 'socialNetwork': 'YouTube', 'uniqueSocialInteractions': None, 'hasSocialSourceReferral': 'Yes', 'socialInteractionNetworkAction': ' : '}, 'latencyTracking': None, 'sourcePropertyInfo': None, 'contentGroup': {'contentGroup1': '(not set)', 'contentGroup2': '(not set)', 'contentGroup3': '(not set)', 'contentGroup4': '(not set)', 'contentGroup5': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup1': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup2': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup3': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup4': '(not set)', 'previousContentGroup5': '(not set)', 'contentGroupUniqueViews1': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews2': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews3': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews4': None, 'contentGroupUniqueViews5': None}, 'dataSource': None, 'publisher_infos': array([], dtype=object)}]"
```

Comment: Just replace `array([], dtype=object)` with a regular `[]`?

Comment: ... or add a `from pandas import array` at the top of your script. `ast.literal_eval()` knows nothing about `pandas.array()` at that point.

Comment: @HenryYik thank you, that is very clever! Should have thought of that..

Comment: @accdias that doesn't seem to do anything..